# Gparted can't resize Ubuntu partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, resize

I installed Ubuntu with Windows. Before installing, I shrunk the space for Ubuntu. Now I have 3.7GB free in my Ubuntu home.That's not enough for me.

So I shrunk my NTFS partition, it's now unalocated. Then I selected ext4 (Ubuntu home) to resize.

But it is 4GB and GParted not allowed to resize more than 4GB. But my 1GB is unallocated.

[image: GParted screenshot]

Comment: See the answer below. Also, you should re size the one below the one you have selected, `/dev/sd8` is your ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 20):

`/dev/sda5` is a logical partition inside an extended partition (`/dev/sda4`), while the unallocated space lies outside of that extended partition.

You need to resize `/dev/sda4` to include the unallocated space first, then resize `/dev/sda8`.

Unfortunately GParted won’t let you touch `/dev/sda4` (note the key symbol), because some of its child partitions are still mounted (more key symbols) and you can’t unmount the root file system on `/dev/sda7`. To circumvent this issue, you need to perform the above procedure from a live system (analogous to [How do I resize root partition?](/q/60431)).

Comment: I can't resize /dev/sda4 (when I right click no option to resize).I can resize the /dev/sda6 but I can't(Minimum and maximum of resize are 15GB).

Comment: I overlooked something there, which I describe in the last paragraph I just added to my answer.

Comment: Note that extending a partition 'backwards' (or something like that - basically expanding it so it fills the space before it) can take a very long time and may damage your data. You will likely want to do backups beforehand. @David great answer :)