# resize Linux(/) partitition to make more space for Windows

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I tried to follow this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585092/gparted-cant-resize-ubuntu-partition) but not very clear what to do?
In my case my partition looks like this
[image]

I want to free up some space from /dev/sda4 which is mounted as "/" and ext4 partiton.
Once i get this free space I want to log into Windows to allocate the free space to Windows parition(C:) /dev/sda3.

**Right now my "/" has 234 GB. I want to reduce it to 100 GB only so that remaining 134 GB can be added to the Windows partition.**

When i am using gparted I am not getting the options to push the resize button as it is greyed out...why?
[image]

Do i need to unmount it first..will Ubuntu will work in that case?

Do I really need to use the live USB for this work.
As this is Linux partition I would like to do it from Linux only...When adding more space to Windows..in that case I will use the Windows tool(please suggest something).

Thanks everybody for your advice/suggestions. I was also following this [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/)
After using live USB, gparted
Shrink the /dev/sda4
Now when increasing windows(/dev/sda3) - i got issues and i have to move shrunk /dev/sda4 to make adjacent space for Windows(/dev/sda3)

Doing both the operations, got one warning message also...
[image]
[image]

Let's see what happens?

**Update**
Was able to shrink Linux's(/) to 111 GB and move it right side to make way for Windows(C:). Also able to expand Windows(C:) to add this remaining GB.

After this my grub was not working which required me to make use of `boot-repair`. During this step - i need to execute these commands:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -fy
sudo apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub*-common grub-common:i386 shim-signed linux-signed*
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-efi-amd64-signed shim-signed linux-signed-generic
```

And finally the paste-bin [contents](http://paste2.org/JW2PPL9U)

Got a lot of un-necessary EFI entries which I can fix following my [strategy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643839/how-to-remove-unnecessary-efi-entries-from-grub).

and then `grub-customizer` to fix the boot order

Everything is working fine now.
Here it looks like after this operation
[image]

Comment: It has to be unmounted but you can't do it from running system (because it is root partition). Boot from `gparted live`

Comment: @EdiD...thanks for the comment...when you say gparted-live do you mean [this](http://gparted.org/livecd.php)? If i am not wrong it is already bundled in [USB-live-USB](http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/), right? I need some more details i think.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant and yes `gparted` is also included in ubuntu live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Linux nor Windows will operate on live partitions, they need to be unmounted. So, you cannot grow or shrink a partition from the OS on the partition itself.

If you need to boot from another partition, a good choice is to boot from the Ubuntu Live medium and start `gparted` from there because you won't have to deal with much differences to your day-to-day Ubuntu.

Boot from the Ubuntu Live medium, start `gparted`, shrink your Linux partition **and** also grow your Windows partition from `gparted`. Do it in one step - it helps avoiding mistakes by booting to the Windows Recovery and working with `diskpart` from Windows. This is a OS-agnostic step. `gparted` is actually the best program to deal with since it has more options and is more user-friendly than `diskpart`.

After this, you can reboot into the system of your choice with the new size.

Comment: I have upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 LTS...Getting the Bootable live USB for 16.04 LTS and will use that.for this purpose. I got it that i need to have this unmounted to resize it...just to be on the safer side...i will only shrink Linux(/) and come out of it...boot everything...if everything is fine..then get into Windows to use the diskpartition utility of Windows to extend Windows C: or make a D: in Windows...one thing at a time is better than trying everything in one go in these kind of scenerios.

Comment: No, you can't. If you boot Windows, the Windows partition is locked for the same reason as in Linux with the Linux partition. You NEED to have another OS from another disk or partition do this step. You could do it from Linux or choose the Windows PE rescue environment. But NOT by booting Windows. 

Look at this as one step, not two. There is no harm in shrinking one partition and growing another with the same tool. It is less error-prone.

Comment: If i am not doing any operation on Windows partition how it is locked? sorry couldn't get this.

Comment: If you get into Windows, you cannot use the diskpart utility on the Windows partition itself. Boot the Windows PE (Windows recovery), you can do it from there because it's a different partition.

Comment: Sorry some more detailed information is needed. As it's related to disk partitioning...somewhat more clear and detailed reasoning is provided. Please provide a detailed answer and I will mark it as a solution.